# Remove everything from character after sign "+" in R

Tags: r, character, gsub

I have data in the following format:

```
2213000
6314931
2224100+ 2224200+ 2224900
```

I would like to remove everything after the first "+" sign for those characters in which "+" appears, while retaining the part of the character before the sign.

In other words, from the example above, I would need to have the following:

```
2213000
6314931
2224100
```

I have tried the following code,

```
my_data <- (gsub("\\+.*", "", mydata))
```

which returns a blank string, whereas I would need to retain the character before the first "+" sign.

Would greatly appreciate any help on how to fix this!

Comment: In my case `sub("\\+.*", "", c("2213000", "6314931", "2224100+ 2224200+ 2224900"))` gives the wanted result.

Comment: Is `mydata` a `vector`?

Comment: If `mydata` is dataframe you need to pass the column value. `mydata$col <- sub("\\+.*", "", mydata$col))`

Comment: Thank you both! Once I passed the column value I the issue was solved. Thank you so much again!